# Angular2 "no exported member bootstrap" error

Tags: angular, typescript

My Atom editor shows:

> Module '"C:/express4/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/index"' has 
>   no exported member 'bootstrap'.at line 2 col 10

For the below import in a TypeScript file:

```
import { bootstrap } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
```

Any idea what could be the reason for this warning?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Assuming you are on Angular RC6/RC5, you can try below code:

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

Comment: Yes , it has worked , so the code that I mentioned works for older versions only ?

Comment: when you say rc6 or rc5 which version you are refering to? 2.0.0 or 2.0.1

Answer (score 0):

I am using ionic2 rc0 and had to add following dependencies as described here https://github.com/driftyco/ionic2-app-base/blob/master/package.json#L15-L24

```
"@angular/common": "^2.0.0",
"@angular/compiler": "^2.0.0",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "^0.6.2",
"@angular/core": "^2.0.0",
"@angular/forms": "^2.0.0",
"@angular/http": "^2.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^2.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.0.0",
"@angular/platform-server": "^2.0.0",
```